# How to configure an ADC using an STM32 in Rust?

Tags: stm32, adc, spi, rust

I want to write values to an external ADC's register through SPI using an STM32 MCU in Rust.

For example, I want to write 0b00000001 to 0x05 register address of ADC3441 to configure it.

The MCU STM32L053 can communicate with ADC3441 through SPI.

How can I accomplish this in Rust that uses the `stm32l0x3_hal`.

I have found codes [here](https://docs.rs/crate/stm32l0xx-hal/0.7.0/source/examples/spi.rs), but I don't understand how I can transfer any values to a register address.

Comment: Did you read [the SPI example](https://docs.rs/crate/stm32l0xx-hal/0.7.0/source/examples/spi.rs)?  It's pretty spare, but it does show how to do an SPI write.  Presumably the SPI crate itself documents the read function.

Comment: Thanks! I did find the SPI example. But I am not sure how I can write 8bit data to a 8bit address. Where the address goes and where the data goes.

Comment: SPI itself doesn't understand "address" and "data" -- if the ADC has the concept of addresses, you have to build that into the data stream.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Then can you please tell me what the loop means in the example code. Does it mean the SPI is going to transfer the values 0 and 1 continuously? I guess I am asking what &[0, 1] means here.

Comment: You're going to have to do some experimentation, but `&[0, 1]` means an array consisting of 0 and then 1; I assume that the write function takes that and writes out 0x00 then 0x01.  I further assume that the loop turns that in to 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 ...

Comment: Having an oscilloscope to verify that would be really good.  Or if it's possible to turn the clock way, way down, put an LED on the clock line and the MOSI line and just watch what happens.

Comment: Great, I am gonna do that. Thanks so much.

Comment: If you find an answer to your original question, please post it.  If you asked, there's 100 people out there who would like to know but couldn't or didn't ask.

Comment: I haven't found the exact answer. I am waiting for a new ADC3441 chip that I can test on. I will surely post the answer.